# How to rotate/transform QMovie in c++

Tags: c++, qt, qmovie

I can rotate `QPixmap` with code like this

```cpp
  QPixmap pix("img.jpg");
  QMatrix rm;
  rm.rotate(90);
  pix = pix.transformed(rm)
```

how can I do same with `QMovie`? Or somehow wrap it into some "container" and rotate that "container"?

Comment: I guess you show the QMovie in a QLabel, and you want the QMovie to be shown rotated, am I correct?

Comment: Yeah, totally correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to rotate frame by frame. For example:

```
m_movie = new QMovie(":/gif/tenor.gif");
connect(m_movie, SIGNAL(frameChanged(int)), this, SLOT(OnFrameChanged(int)));
ui->lblMovie->setMovie(m_movie);
m_movie->start();
```

And rotate every frame when frame changed

```
void MainWindow::OnFrameChanged(int /*frame*/)
{
    QPixmap pixmap = m_movie->currentPixmap();
    QMatrix rm;
    rm.rotate(90);
    pixmap = pixmap.transformed(rm);
    ui->lblMovRotated->setPixmap(pixmap);
}
```